# Finding how many times a movie was rented in the year it was released

Tags: sqlite

I have a setup like so:

```
Movies (
    movieId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    year INTEGER
)

Rentals (
    cardNo INTEGER,
    movieId INTEGER,
    date DATE,
    rating INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(cardNo, movieID, date),
    FOREIGN KEY (cardNo) REFERENCES Customers,
    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies
)
```

and I want to figure out which movie(s) were rented the most amount of times in a given year if and only if the movie was released that year.

For example: If movie_x was rented the most in 2003 but was not also released in 2003, then it cannot count. If movie_y was both released in 2003 and rented the most (of the movies released that year) in 2003 then it does count.

I am thinking I need to setup a temporary table that stores the `movieId` and the `count(movieId)` so that I can then perform a select `max()` on the count, but I am unsure how to go about it.

I am using python, so I can store the the `movieId` of the `max()` in a variable and then check the original `movies` column to match it to the title of the movie, if that helps.

Comment: Would only ever be reporting on a single year at a time, or would your report have multiple years?

Comment: It could contain multiple years. I think the thing that I am struggling with the most is creating a temporary table that has the columns of movie id and # of times rented as long as the movie was released in the given year and rented in the given year. If I can figure out how to do that then I can run a max() query on its # of times rented column and find the movie id which I can then link to the movie title.

Comment: I tried an answer below.  Some sample data would have been helpful.

Comment: What do you want in case of ties?

Comment: @Shawn all movies that tie should be included. What I am really looking for is a way to create a temporary table that includes the movie id and the number of times the movie was rented in the given year as long as the movie was also released in the given year. I can work it out from there pretty easily.

Comment: What format is used for the dates in the rental table?  Is it `2018-10-05`, or something else?

Comment: That is the format, yes. YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy used in this answer is to join the `Rental` and `Movies` tables together on matching `movieID` and year.  This serves to discard any records from the `Rentals` table which did not occur in the same year a movie was released.

We can aggregate such a join, which would then generate year/movie rentals counts for the entire database.  But, since you only want movies having the highest rental count for a given year, we need to do more work.  In this case, we can find the highest rental count for each year (see subquery `t2` below), and join to the subquery described earlier.

```
SELECT
    t1.movieId,
    t1.title,
    t1.year,
    t1.num_rentals
FROM
(
    SELECT
        m.movieId,
        m.title,
        m.year,
        COUNT(*) AS num_rentals
    FROM Rentals r
    INNER JOIN Movies m
        ON r.movieId = m.movieId AND CAST(SUBSTR(r.date, 1, 4) AS INTEGER) = m.year
    GROUP BY
        m.movieId,
        m.title,
        m.year
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT year, MAX(num_rentals) AS max_num_rentals
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.year,
            COUNT(*) AS num_rentals
        FROM Rentals r
        INNER JOIN Movies m
            ON r.movieId = m.movieId AND CAST(SUBSTR(r.date, 1, 4) AS INTEGER) = m.year
        GROUP BY
            m.movieId,
            m.year
    ) t
    GROUP BY year
) t2
    ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.num_rentals = t2.max_num_rentals
-- WHERE t1.year = 2003
ORDER BY
    t1.year;
```

### Demo

This answer will report all years, along with all movies released in that year having the highest rental counts.  In the case of ties for two or more movies in a given year, *all* tied movies would be reported.

Note that if SQLite supported analytic functions, the query could be greatly simplified.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to follow what is going on here because I am pretty new to SQL. Is there not a way to just create a temporary table that includes the movie id in one column and the number of times the movie was rented and only have an entry for the movie if the rental and release date of the movie occurred in the given year? I also ran this on the db and it does not seem to work properly. It is returning the wrong movies.

Comment: @Mdomin45 I think we can make the above query work for you.  Please try it and leave feedback, thanks.

Comment: Where would I put in the given year? Say I want to check for the year 2000.

Comment: Hard coding for a given year would change the whole query, and since you didn't ask for this, I'm reluctant to change my entire answer.  A quick way to do this would be to just add a `WHERE` clause to the outer query, see my updated answer.

Comment: It is still giving me the incorrect answer. I wish I could shed more light as to why, but the db that I'm using is quite large and I have very little understanding of the code itself.

Comment: OK...I will try creating some mock data, and then run my query against it.  In the meantime, if you can add some sample data to your question, that would be good.

Comment: The thing is what I am truly looking to do is create a temporary table that has the movie id in one column and the number of times the movie was rented in another column, with movies only being included in the temporary table if they were released in a given year, and the count of the times it was rented only going up by 1 if the rent occurred during its release year. Then I can simply run max(numberOfTimesRented) on it and get the desired output.

Comment: @Mdomin45 Check the demo I setup.  The query seems to be working, so maybe your data has a problem.  You _don't_ need a temp table here; that's not the way to do reporting in SQL, unless you plan on using something like a materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach, using CTEs instead of nested subqueries.

```
WITH first_year_rentals(movieid, title, rentals, year) AS
      (SELECT m.movieid, m.title, count(*), m.year 
       FROM movies AS m 
       JOIN rentals AS r ON m.movieid = r.movieid AND m.year = strftime('%Y', r.date)
       GROUP BY m.movieid)
    , maximums(year, maxrent) AS
      (SELECT year, max(rentals)
       FROM first_year_rentals
       GROUP BY year)
SELECT movieid, title, rentals, f.year AS year
FROM first_year_rentals AS f
JOIN maximums AS m ON f.year = m.year AND m.maxrent = f.rentals 
ORDER BY f.year, title;
```

A CTE (Common Table Expression) is like a view that only exists for the one statement. Very handy for organizing a statement with multiple queries. The first one generates results that count the number of times each movie was rented in the year it came out. The second one is the highest rental count for each year's new releases. Then it's just a matter of joining the two CTEs and limiting the results to just rows where the rental count equals the highest for that movie's release year.

Edit:

Tested using these tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
    movieId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    year INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(1,'a good movie',2003);
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(2,'a better movie',2003);
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(3,'the best movie',2004);
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(4,'the worst movie',2004);
CREATE TABLE Rentals (
    cardNo INTEGER,
    movieId INTEGER,
    date DATE,
    rating INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(cardNo, movieID, date),
    -- FOREIGN KEY (cardNo) REFERENCES Customers,
    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies
);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(1,1,'2003-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(1,2,'2003-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(1,3,'2006-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(2,1,'2003-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(2,3,'2004-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(2,2,'2004-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(3,2,'2003-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(3,1,'2005-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(3,4,'2004-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(4,2,'2003-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(4,4,'2004-01-01',NULL);
INSERT INTO Rentals VALUES(5,1,'2003-01-01',NULL);
```

Giving:

```
movieid     title           rentals     year      
----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
2           a better movie  3           2003      
1           a good movie    3           2003      
4           the worst movi  2           2004
```

### Demo

Further edits:

The mention of analytic functions in the other answer reminded me; sqlite **does** have them these days (Added in 3.25)! So...

```
WITH first_year_rentals(movieid, title, rentals, maxrentals, year) AS
     (SELECT m.movieid
           , m.title
           , count(*)
           , max(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.year)
           , m.year
      FROM movies AS m 
      JOIN rentals AS r ON m.movieid = r.movieid AND m.year = strftime('%Y', r.date)
      GROUP BY m.movieid)
SELECT movieid, title, rentals, year
FROM first_year_rentals 
WHERE rentals = maxrentals
ORDER BY year, title;
```

It uses a window function to combine the two CTEs from the first query into a single one. (There might be an even better way; I'm not super fluent with them yet).

And a different version using the rank suggestion:

```
WITH first_year_rentals(movieid, title, rentals, ranking, year) AS
     (SELECT m.movieid
           , m.title
           , count(*)
           , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY m.year ORDER BY count(*) DESC)
           , m.year
      FROM movies AS m 
      JOIN rentals AS r ON m.movieid = r.movieid AND m.year = strftime('%Y', r.date)
      GROUP BY m.movieid)
SELECT movieid, title, rentals, year
FROM first_year_rentals 
WHERE ranking = 1
ORDER BY year, title;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated. I suspect your fiddle isn't working because you're not using actual tables with an appropriate affinity for the year column, which means that the string returned by `strftime()` isn't converted into a number and that comparison thus fails. Sqlite can be tricky and non-obvious sometimes with when it converts values in comparisons.

Comment: Yeah, it looks good now +1.  Unfortunately, my brain is too fried to try to understand your query, but it seems to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I threw up a second version using window functions that fries my brain too. Those things are black magic.

Comment: OK...another way would be to use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` with a partition on year, and an `ORDER BY` on the count descending.  Then, retain only rank = 1 records (which would capture all ties for first place).